# SQL Use column values as column names in query count results

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-athena

I have a table that includes `tdate` and `node_name` as columns, among other things.

```
tdate                   node_name
2021-04-15 15:37:04.000 node1
2021-04-15 15:37:04.000 node2
2021-04-15 15:37:04.000 node1
2021-04-15 15:37:04.000 node3
2021-04-15 15:37:04.000 node1
```

I want to plot a count of instances of `node_name` group by the `tdate`. So doing something like this

```
SELECT
date_trunc('minute',tdate),
node_name,
count(1)
GROUP BY 1,2
```

I get

```
_col0                    node_name      _col2
2021-04-15 15:37:00.000   node1           3
2021-04-15 15:37:00.000   node2           1
2021-04-15 15:37:00.000   node3           1
```

What I would like to see is

```
_col0                   node1 node2 node3
2021-04-15 15:37:00.000 3     1     1
```

I know I cause use `sum(node_name = 'node1') as 'node1'` etc, but the issue is that there are potentially hundreds of unique node names depending on the query and its unfeasible to use `sum()` or `count(case )` statements. Is there some way to generalize it without explicitly including each node_name value? (`sum(node_name) as node_name`)?

Comment: I don't think that you can do it in SQL. You can think about creating the SQL programmatically based on the nodes that you find in the data. The simplest way is to get the long list and turn it to wide with external libraries such as Pandas in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `histogram` function that will return a map of your columns with the respective counts, see the doc here: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html